# Flash Projector wont open .swf's only black screen

Tags: wine, flash, swf

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I want to be able to run .swf's file's (A game called Realm of the mad god) I use Wine to open the flash projector and then run the .swf. I get a black screen with audio. How do I fix this. I've tried everything on the forums and nothing seems to work any help would be appreciated. I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 32 Bit

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?